# File upload with invalid path doesnt fail test

Tags: karate

Below is the sample code which is suppoe to fail as the file path is invalid.

```
  Scenario: test input
    * driver "https://fineuploader.com/demos.html"
    * print "performing file upload"
    * input("[name='qqfile']","in valid path")
    * print "done file upload"
```

I see the error on the console

```
12:03:27.773 [chromedriver_1584979407695] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [/Users/vxt82/Apps/chromedriver, --port=9515, --user-data-dir=/Users/vxt82/repo/bitbucket/xtaf-unified-framwork/target/chromedriver_1584979407695]
12:03:31.648 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] performing file upload

12:03:31.711 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] WARN  com.intuit.karate - http response code: 404, response: {"value":{"stacktrace":"0   chromedriver                        0x0000000108d72e99 chromedriver + 3747481\n1   chromedriver                        0x0000000108d074d3 chromedriver + 3306707\n2   chromedriver                        0x0000000108a96fef chromedriver + 749551\n3   chromedriver                        0x0000000108a03128 chromedriver + 143656\n4   chromedriver                        ....            0x00007fff767a040d thread_start + 13\n","error":"no such element","message":"no such element: Element_id length is invalid\n  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.50)"}}, request: [method: POST, responseTime: 4.207512, body: {"text":"in valid path"}]
12:03:31.718 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] done file upload
```

I was expecting test to fail but surprisingly it's passing.  I looked into documentation but did not find anything specific to this scenarios.

Is this is expected behaviour, or I am doing some mistake in understanding?

Comment: maybe you should just add an assertion ? anyway, follow these instructions and we can fix if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate's file upload (input()) works similar to Selenium WebDrivers sendkeys(). It just does setting the text without validating is it file type and a path, Which I think is ok and as per design. May be as suggested Peter assertion can help at some extent to confirm file upload works.